# How to extract labels from the path?

Tags: neo4j

I have the query

```
MATCH (rootPerson:Person {uuid: '650wer0a-2374-11e6-aabd-ce6wqe3145e4'})
MATCH (mother:Rerson)<-[rel:MOTHER*0..4]-(rootPerson)
WITH mother
SKIP 1
MATCH (children:Person)-[:MOTHER]->(mother)
MATCH (grand_children:Person)-[:FATHER|:MOTHER]->(children)
OPTIONAL MATCH (grand_children)-[:STUDY_AT]->(uni:University)...
```

And the problem is that neo4j matches not just grand_children but children and parents as well, and it's very slow down speed and returns a lot of useles extra data, how can I do matching only with grand_children?

Comment: It would be nice to see an example of input data and the desired result. And just how do you try to get this result.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting multiple generations for `grand_children` because you are unnecessarily using a variable-length path pattern (via the `*0..4` syntax).

This should work properly:

```
MATCH (rootPerson:Person {uuid: '650wer0a-2374-11e6-aabd-ce6wqe3145e4'})
MATCH (rootPerson)-[:MOTHER]->(mother:Person)
MATCH (children:Person)-[:MOTHER]->(mother:Person)
MATCH (grand_children:Person)-[:FATHER|:MOTHER]->(children)
OPTIONAL MATCH (grand_children)-[:STUDY_AT]->(uni:University)
...
```